# What is the Psi(x) variable binding operator?

Tags: notation

In the [Free Variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variable) article on Wikipedia, it lists these:

[image: variable-binding operators]

as variable-binding operators. I have seen all of them during my math studies, except for the psi operator. What does $\psi x$ mean in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what was intended by $\psi$ here, but some Wikipedia archaeology reveals that it was introduced in [this edit](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Free_variables_and_bound_variables&diff=229988162&oldid=228192578), and [the same user tried to remove it again one minute later](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Free_variables_and_bound_variables&diff=next&oldid=229988162). They made a mess out of the removal, and [Michael Hardy undid the mess](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Free_variables_and_bound_variables&diff=next&oldid=229988401), leaving in the $\psi x$ with no explanation. None is likely forthcoming, because the user who added the $\psi x$, back in August 2008, [has not been back to Wikipedia since](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aContributions/Iitmadras).

In short, it is most likely a piece of Wikipedia nonsense. Unless someone posts  a definitive answer here, I will shortly remove the $\psi x$ from the Wikipedia article.

As a consolation prize, here are some other variable binding operators you may not be familiar with, which are not in the Wikipedia article:

- Robin Milner's $\pi$-calculus uses "$\nu x. F$" to denote an expression F in which $x$ is instantiated to a "new" variable that has never been used before within the scope of the current computation.
- Whitehead and Russell use "$\iota x.\Phi(x)$" to denote the unique $x$ satisfying some description $\Phi(x)$.  For example, "$\iota x. x$ is the King of Swaziland" is an expression denoting the King of Swaziland.
- Hilbert used "$\epsilon x.\phi(x)$" to denote "some value for which $\phi$ is true". That is, for any property $\phi$, if $\exists v.\phi(x)$ is true,then so is $\phi(\epsilon x.\phi(x))$.
- Similarly, Hilbert used $\mu x.\phi(x)$ to denote the smallest natural number for which $\phi$ is true.
- Category theorists often use $\exists!x.\phi(x)$ as an abbreviation for $\exists x\forall y.\phi(x) \land (\phi(y)\implies y=x)$, or some equivalent variation of it. It says that there is *exactly one* $x$ for which $\phi(x)$ holds.

Commonly-used quantifiers that do not seem to have any standard compact notation include "almost everywhere" and "all but finitely many".

Comment: $\exists !$ is a standard abbreviation and not peculiar to category theorists.

Comment: Thanks. I was careful in my phrasing not to rule out the use of $\exists !$ by non-category theorists. Please feel free to edit my answer if you have anything concrete to add.

Comment: That archaeology is convincing enough on its own that I've just boldly gone ahead and deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

My first impulse in seeing ‘$\varphi x$’ is to read it as a variation on the logical schema (‘$\varphi(x)$’, ‘$F x$’, etc.), which, if that was the intented meaning, should, I believe, preclude it from a list of variable-binding operators. I would vote up for removal from the article if I could.